# Naming lower and upper threshold of a metric

Tags: naming

I am creating an API that will expose a list of metrics data. Each metric data will contain the following:

```
metricName
lowerThreshold
upperThreshold
```

The defined thresholds here are what will determine whether the current value of the metric is good or bad.

---

The behavior of the application will be based on how the current value of the metric compares to the bounds

**CASE 1**

> If metric is lower than upperThreshold -> `Warning`
>
> If metric is lower than lowerThreshold -> `Action`

The prefix **`upper`** and **`lower`** will not always hold true. There are metrics where the objective is to minimize a number, in which case the `upperThreshold` will be **lower than** the `lowerThreshold`

**CASE 2**

> If metric is higher than upperThreshold -> `Warning`
>
> If metric is higher than lowerThreshold -> `Action`

What would be the right way to name these bounds such that there is no confusion regarding which one is the better metric without inferring anything about the relationship between the 2 bounds?

Comment: If you have a metric which you want to maximize (bigger is better), would you still have some upper bound (too big, too much good)?

Comment: Yes. But it would not mean what your thinking. Any metric must always be above the lowerThreshold and should ideally be above the upperThreshold. Maybe the term `thershold` in itself could be misleading.

Comment: If metric is lower than upperThreshold -> Warning
If metric is lower than lowerThreshold -> Action

Comment: "Bound" in the title might be more misleading that "threshold".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about incorporating the implication into your flip value rather than a meaningless "lower" or "upper"?

ActionThreshold and WarningThreshold.

Whether the implication would be effective above or below could differ but should be clear from context.

Comment: Or, alternatively: (action) -- WarningThr. -- (warning) -- ErrorThr. -- (error), if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

> If metric is lower than upperThreshold, then Warning.
>   If metric is lower than lowerThreshold, then Action.
>   [For cases when bigger is better.]

I propose this naming scheme.  Prefix "minimum" for metrics where larger value is better.   Prefix "maximum" for values where smaller values is better.  Suffix "recommended" for warning thresholds.  Suffix "required" for action threshold (or no suffix at all for action threshold).

A metric where larger values are better would have:
`minimumRecommended` for Warnig threshold
`minimumRequired` (or simply `minimum`) for Action threshold,

A metric where smaller values are better would have:
`maximumRecommended` for Warning threshold, 
`maximumRequired` (or simply `maximum`) for Action threshold,

Comment: So you are saying I should have a different schema for metrics based on whether they are a maximizing metric of a minimizing metric?

Comment: Different prefixes for maximizing or minimizing.  (I'd still call it all one schema.)